# Send email to SharePoint Group on selected file using Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, modern-document-library

I would like to send an email to SharePoint Group on selected file from Document library using Power Automate.

Comment: Where are you having issues? Is it the trigger or getting the members of the SharePoint group or something else?

Comment: I want to perform manual action by selecting file one or more from library and send email to sharepoint group, where group consist of 10 or 15